# How can I find the y-position of background image in pixels using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a background image set up using following code.

```
background-image: url('url');
background-position: center;
background-size: contain;
```

This will place the image on center of div.

[image]

Is there any method or calculation to find the width(question mark in image) in pixel?

Comment: `(container.height - bg.height) / 2` Although, if you just want the `y` position of the bg you can use `offset().top`

Comment: can you explain about how `offset().top`

Comment: If you have the image ratio that is easily accomplished by using Rory McCrossman formula but using the calculated BG height using the container width and image ratio.

Comment: @underscore http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: @MarioCesar can you please send me link to find the image ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you don't know the image ratio.

```
//getting the image URL (code from [here][1])
var url = $('CONTAINER_SELECTOR').css('background-image').replace(/^url\(['"]?/,'').replace(/['"]?\)$/,'');

//creating the image
var img = new Image;

img.src = url;

//WARNING: Im not dealing with the "image loaded" question.

var ratio = null;
if(img.height){
   ratio = img.width / height;
}


var containerWidth = $('CONTAINER_SELECTOR').innerWidth();

var difference = ($('CONTAINER_SELECTOR').innerHeight() - (containerWidth / ratio)) / 2);
```

**I didn't test it**. Later on I'll do a jsfiddle if necessary.

**BEWARE**: The code above might need tweaking when the ratio of the container is below 1 and the image's ratio is above 1 and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

```
<body>

<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<p></p>

<script>
var p = $( "p:first" );
var position = p.position();
$( "p:last" ).text( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );
</script>

</body>
```

or

```
<script>
var p = $( "p:last" );
var offset = p.offset();
p.html( "left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );
</script>
```

Comment: offset()
Get the current offset of the first matched element, in pixels, relative to the document.

position()
Gets the top and left position of an element relative to its offset parent.